# Fastest available Delaunay triangulation algorithm for GPU

Tags: geometry, parallel-processing, gpu, triangulation

Which is in your opinion the fastest available Delaunay triangulation algorithm for GPU? Or more general, in parallel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be careful with GPU's: Delaunay Triangulations require orientation tests. These do not work reliably with floating point arithmetic, and it might be hard to cope with that
problem using a GPU. Also the memory management is crucial.

You might want to try http://www.geom.at/fade2d/html/ which is among the fastest robust
single threaded implementations.

Answer (score 26):

**2D Delaunay triangulation**

**[GPU-DT](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~tants/delaunay2DDownload.html)** is the fastest 2D Delaunay implementation for the GPU.

It constructs a digital Voronoi diagram in 2D using the GPU **Parallel Banding Algorithm**. Next it fixes and dualizes this to obtain a 2D triangulation. Finally, it performs edge-flipping in parallel on the GPU to obtain the 2D Delaunay triangulation.

**3D Delaunay triangulation**

[**gStar4D**](https://github.com/ashwin/gstar4d) is a fast and robust implementation of 3D Delaunay for the GPU.

Similar to GPU-DT, this algorithm constructs the 3D digital Voronoi diagram first. However, in 3D this cannot be dualized to a triangulation due to topological and geometrical problems. Instead, gStar4D uses the neighborhood information from this diagram to create stars lifted to 4D and performs star splaying on them efficiently on the GPU. By extracting the lower hull from this, the 3D Delaunay triangulation is obtained.

A faster alternative is [**gDel3D**](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/%7Etants/gdel3d.html), which is a hybrid GPU-CPU algorithm.

It performs parallel insertion and flipping on the GPU. The result is close to Delaunay. It then fixes this result using a conservative star splaying method on the CPU.

All these methods are robust, so they can handle any kind of degenerate input.

Comment: The links to the code in the GPU-DT link are dead. The code that seems to supersede it (i.e. gDel2D) is much slower than a CPU implementation from my experiments (e.g. 500ms vs 300ms). The CPU implementation that I use is a modification of: https://github.com/abellgithub/delaunator-cpp and it was tested with 565055 non-uniformly distributed points.